# Question regarding value returned from WebAuthenticationDetails.getRemoteAddress()

Tags: spring, spring-security, ip-address

I am writing a custom AccessDecisionVoter that will allow access to certain resources only if the remote address of the request is found in a list of allow ip addresses.  However, the value of the remote address returned by WebAuthenticationDetails.getRemoteAddress() is in a format that appears to be Ipv6.  When running my app locally, this is what is returned by the above method:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0
```

I'm storing the allowed address in a comma-delimited list in a properties file.  The list is parsed and each allowed address is compared to the remote address, but since I have no idea how to translate an Ipv4 address into an Ipv6 address this comparison will always fail.

So is the value that is always returned by WebAuthenticationDetails.getRemoteAddress() or am I seeing this only because I'm running this locally?

Is there some way to convert this string to an Ipv4 string?

Is there some way to have the method in question return an Ipv4 string instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert an IPv6 address to an IPv4 address. The represent two different protocols. The address of `getRemoteAddress()` will be in a format depending on the protocol used to create the request to the webapp. I guess that you see the IPv6 address only when using the app locally. `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` is the address of `localhost`, which is the same as `127.0.0.1` in IPv4. I think you should simply add this IPv6 address to the list of allowed IPs.

Comment: Thanks chkal, I will definitely add that address to the allowed list.